# Adding new row to the tables and fill with defined values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fill reports tables with specific data in the filled form, when doing so, it works well with the sheets with one table but with more table it cannot while the code is right as I think, I think there is something to do to make it do the needed well. so your kind assistance will be highly appreciated either by correcting the code or provide other way. thanks in advance

```
Private Sub Search_Click() ' firstly I do search
Dim cRow As String
On Error Resume Next
cRow = Me.txtSearch.Value
'find the name of the employee written on the search box in column B
Set FindRow = Sheets("Current Payroll").Range("B:B").Find
(what:=cRow,LookIn:=xlValues)
 If Not FindRow Is Nothing Then '<-- successful find
    'add the values to the userform
Me.txtname.Value = FindRow.Value
Me.txtposition.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1).Text
Me.Locationtxt.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 4).Text
End If
End Sub


Private Sub UpdateAdavance_Click()
Dim the_Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim the_Sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim cRow As Integer
Dim table_list_object As ListObject
Dim table_object_row As ListRow
Dim x As Integer
On Error Resume Next
'find the row with the data on the search box
Set FindRow = Sheets("Current Payroll").Range("B7:B").
Find(what:=cRow, LookIn:=xlValues)
'add the values to  deduction report table number 3
Set the_Sheet1 = Sheets("Deduction Report")
Set table_list_object = the_Sheet1.ListObjects(3)
Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add
table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Value = Me.txtname.Text
table_object_row.Range(1, 2).Value = Me.txtposition.Text
table_object_row.Range(1, 3).Value = Me.Locationtxt.Text
table_object_row.Range(1, 4).Value = Me.txtadvance.Value
table_object_row.Range(1, 5).Value = Format(Me.Datetxt.Value, "mmmm dd, yy")
table_object_row.Range(1, 6).Value = Me.AdvanceReason.Text
'add the values to  current month report table number5
Set the_Sheet2 = Sheets("current month report ")
Set table_list_object = the_Sheet2.ListObjects(5)
Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add
table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Value = Me.txtname.Text
table_object_row.Range(1, 2).Value = Me.txtposition.Text
table_object_row.Range(1, 3).Value = Me.Locationtxt.Text
table_object_row.Range(1, 4).Value = Me.txtadvance.Value
table_object_row.Range(1, 5).Value = Format(Me.Datetxt.Value, "mmmm dd, yy")
table_object_row.Range(1, 6).Value = Me.AdvanceReason.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Disable the On Error Resume next temporarily so that your code can stop when an error is encountered. Then deal with the errors you get, if necessary ask for help here. I also suggest that you get rid of about 200 underscrores in your code. Surely Ws1 would identify a worksheet just as well as the_Sheet1, Tbl as well as table_list_object.

Comment: I removed the on error resume next, and the following error shows    Run-time error '1004': application -define or object define error. this message shown on the following code Set FindRow = Sheets("Current Payroll").Range("B7:B").Find(what:=cRow, LookIn:=xlValues)

Comment: by the way, FindRow is defined as Dim FindRow at the top of the codes for multiple codes

Comment: `Range("B7:B")` is not a valid `Range`, you need to add an ending row, such as `Range("B7:B20")`. Also, it's better if you define `Dim FindRow As Range`

Comment: hi Shai, I did as you mentioned and the problem now is shown in this part of the code (Settableobjectrow = tablelistobject.ListRows.Add) and the message appear says ( this will not work because it would move cells in a table on your worksheet) so please advise how I can solve such issue